# Why my table caption shift line!

Tags: tables

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEEtran} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Arnold period in different size images}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Size N & 4*4 & 8*8 & 32*32 & 64*64 & 128*128 & 256*256\\
    \hline
    Period M & 3 & 6 & 24 & 48 & 96 & 192\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which shift do you mean? And it's not necessary to post a screen shot of the code after you have already posted (a fragment only) code ;-)

Comment: caption is below table I, I want them in the same line

Comment: Could you please stop editing the improvements away -- you're constantly disrupting the code and the caption is **above**, not below

Comment: I tried wiki table caption example, the grammar is almost the same, when I open a new doc and copy it. it show table I and name are in same line. but when I copy the wiki example to this doc. It is in two line again!!

Comment: You're apparently using a document class where the header “Table 1” is printed above the caption text (which is then printed uppercase). Without knowing what document class, it's impossible to say more. If the document is meant for submission and you're forced to use that class, don't worry at all and do as they want.

Comment: this is my class, I have to use IEEE format. any other class recommended?

Comment: @user92322 If you *have* to use IEEE format, do it.

Comment: If you have been told to use IEEE then not only do you need to use it, you need to not interfere with its formatting. That is, you aren't meant to change the format of captions etc. That is the point of telling you to use that class. It ensures that e.g. the captions of all articles in a journal or proceedings are formatted in the same way. Individual authors don't get to choose their formats because the result would be a mess.